# How to loop same variable with different result

Tags: python

Hi I've got a school project which requires me to code a program that asks a user for their details it will then ask what them what size pizza they want and how many ingredients. It will then ask if they want another pizza. It will repeat this until they say no or they have six pizzas.

I don't really know how to explain my issues but I don't know how to loop the code so it asks for another pizza and each one has a different size and amount of toppings. I also don't know how I would print it.
Sorry if this is asking a lot or its confusing to understand or if the code is just painful to look at ahaha.

Thanks in advance.

```
CustomerName = input("Please input the customers name: ")
CustomerAddress = input("Please input the customers address: ")
CustomerNumber = input("Please input the customers number: ")
while True:
    PizzaSize = input("Please input pizza size, Small/Medium/Large: ")
    try:
        PizzaSize = str(PizzaSize)
        if PizzaSize == "Small" or "Medium" or "Large":
            break
        else:
            print("Size not recognized")
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
    
if PizzaSize == "Small":
    SizeCost = 3.25
elif PizzaSize == "Medium":
    SizeCost = 5.50
elif PizzaSize == "Large":
    SizeCost = 7.15





print(SizeCost)

while True:
    ExtraToppings = input("Any extra toppings, 0/1/2/3/4+ ? ")
    try:
        ExtraToppings = float(ExtraToppings)
        if ExtraToppings >= 0 and ExtraToppings <= 4:
            break
        else:
            print("Please insert a number over 0")
    except:
        print("Input not recognised")

if ExtraToppings == 1:
    ToppingCost = 0.75
elif ExtraToppings == 2:
    ToppingCost = 1.35
elif ExtraToppings == 3:
    ToppingCost = 2.00
elif ExtraToppings >= 4:
    ToppingCost = 2.50
else:
    print("Number not recognized")
print(ToppingCost)
``
```

Comment: You need to find a way to save the data you're collecting from your customers, so I would advise you to look at the different data sturctures that can be used in python, for example take a look at dictionaries (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) or pandas dataframes (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html). The right data structure will allow you to count how many pizzas you have so far (with their details), and of course loop through them when needed (for printing for example)

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any such destructive edits will be reverted. Please see [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221) for more information on how deleting content works on this site.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should put the code from the second while loop in the first. There is no need for two while true loops. Then instead of

```
while True:
```

just put

```
pizza_count = 0     # how many pizzas they have
wantsAnotherPizza = True    

while pizza_count < 6 and wantsAnotherPizza:   # while they have less than 6 pizzas and they want another one
    pizza_count += 1    # increase pizza_count as they order another pizza

    # ... your code here from both of the while loops

    x = input("Do you want another pizza? (Y/N)")
    if x == "N" or x == "n":
        global wantsAnotherPizza
        wantsAnotherPizza = False:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code like this. I thing you can simply your conditionals by using dictionaries. Try this

```
from collections import defaultdict
customer_order = defaultdict(list)

customer_order['CustomerName'] = input("Please input the customers name: ")
customer_order['CustomerAddress'] = input("Please input the customers address: ")
customer_order['CustomerNumber'] = input("Please input the customers number: ")

pizza_size ={
    'small':3.25,
    'medium': 5.50,
    'large': 7.15
}

toppins= {'1': 0.75,
 '2':1.35,
'3':2.00,
 '4':2.50,
         }



order = int(input("How many orders would you like to make: "))

while order:
    PizzaSize = input("Please input pizza size, Small/Medium/Large: ").lower()
    ExtraToppings = input("Any extra toppings, 0/1/2/3/4+ ? ")
    try:
        if PizzaSize in pizza_size:
            size_cost= pizza_size[PizzaSize]
            if ExtraToppings:
                ToppingCost= toppins[ExtraToppings]
            else:
                print("Number not recognized")
                continue

            customer_order['order'].extend([{'size':PizzaSize,'toppings': ToppingCost}])
          
            order -= 1
        else:
            print("Size not recognized")
            continue
    except Exception as  msg:
        print("Invalid input", msg)
        continue
else:
    print('Your order is complete')
    print(customer_order)
```